# not able to send ZPL to Zebra zd420 printer via USB in Android

Tags: android, zebra-printers, thermal-printer

I want to print via USB cable with Zebra zd420 printer but data was not sending to printer. I have tried with Zebra GK420 it working fine.

```
    fun print(connection: UsbDeviceConnection?, usbInterface: UsbInterface?, zplData: String, totalPrint:Int=1): Boolean {
        var testBytes = zplData.toByteArray()
        if (usbInterface == null) {
            Utility.showToast(resources.getString(R.string.local_printer_interface_error), Constants.ERROR)
        }
        else if (connection == null) {
            Utility.showToast(resources.getString(R.string.local_printer_connection_error), Constants.ERROR)
        }
        else if (forceCLaim == null) {
            Utility.showToast(resources.getString(R.string.local_printer_force_claim_error), Constants.ERROR)
        }
//        else if (!printerReady) {
//            Utility.showToast(resources.getString(R.string.local_printer_not_connected),Constants.ERROR)
//        }
        else {
            connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, forceCLaim)
            Utility.showToast("I'm reached")
            val thread = Thread(Runnable {
                for(i in  0 until totalPrint) {
                    val cut_paper = byteArrayOf(0x1D, 0x56, 0x41, 0x10)
//                    val cut_paper = byteArrayOf(58, 0xAC.toByte(), 0x82.toByte(), 0x20)
                    connection.bulkTransfer(mEndPoint, testBytes, testBytes!!.size, 0)
                    connection.bulkTransfer(mEndPoint, cut_paper, cut_paper.size, 0)
                }
            })
            thread.run()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

That is my zpl data

```
var data = "^XA ^CFA,20^A0N,30,35^FOR ^FO${80 + x},${30 + y}^FDDispatch Date:${Utility.getTime("dd-MM-yyyy")} ^FS ^FX Third section with barcode. ^BY2,1,120 ^FO${100 + x},${80 + y}^BC^FD0123456789^FS ^A0N,30,35^FO${80 + x},${270 + y}^FDPicked By:${ Utility.printInitials(Utility.getPreference("name")) } ^FS ^A0N,30,35^FO${80 + x},${300 + y}^FDPicked At:${Utility.getTime("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")}^FS^XZ"
```

Comment: Have you send the same ZPL code to both printers? Please add it ot them to the question.

Comment: Yes, I'm sending same zpl for both.

Comment: Please add the ZPL code to the question, not as a comment.